# jQuery ohny fire when Form is valid in browser

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I'm trying to get a jQuery event to only fire once the Form is valid - not using any extensions.
For example I have an email field:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="info@example.com" aria-describedby="emailHelp"  name="email" maxlength="250" required>
```

Inside a Form. Once the submit button is clicked, this event fires:

```
    $("#submitForm").click(function() {
        $("#spinnerSubmit").removeAttr('hidden');
    });
```

But if the user does not put an correct email in the right format, the event fires but the Form still waits for an email input.
Can i somehow check if the form is validated browser-sided, without using any overkill extensions? Or is my only option [this](https://jqueryvalidation.org/valid/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most existing answers, especially tagged [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) will point you to jquery validation.

HTML5 includes some form validation, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Constraint_validation#constraint_validation_process

In summary (of that page), you can call `checkValidity` on a DOM element or form, eg:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").checkValidity();
```

Here's an example (jquery just used for events/UI):

```js
$("#submitForm").click(function() {
  var isValid = document.getElementById("myForm").checkValidity();
  
  $("p").text(isValid);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="myForm">
  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="info@example.com" aria-describedby="emailHelp" name="email" maxlength="250" required>
</form>
<button type='button' id='submitForm'>click me</button>
<p>waiting for click</p>
```

You could also use `$("#myForm")[0].checkValidity()` but left that out of the example to save confusion over jquery/DOM and `[0]` or use vanilla for the UI updates.